# Sails.js filter based on many to many relationship

Tags: many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

I have an hierarchy of categories, set using a many-to-many relationship:

**Category:**

```
name: 'string',
children: {
  collection: 'category',
  via: 'parents',
  dominant: true
},
parents: {
  collection: 'category',
  via: 'children'
}
```

I would like to get a list of the top categories: all categories with an empty 'parents' field.

I managed to do that by going through all categories and checking manually:

```
Category.find()
  .populate('parents')
  .exec(function (err, categories) {
    var topCategories =[];

    var done = _.after(categories.length,function(){
      res.ok(topCategories)
    })

    _.forEach(categories, function (category) {
      if (category.parents.length == 0)
        topCategories.push(category);
      done();
    })
  })
```

My question is if there's a more efficient solution, as mine won't scale to large numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that [it's not possible yet](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/281)